# Battleing people that you have battled before

Tags: clash-of-clans

Can you attack people in Clash of Clans you have already attacked? Because I cannot find a way to do it, I have tried going to battle history and can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't directly opt to fight an opponent you fought before.  You can't even revenge attack someone who revenge attacked you.  In Clan Wars, even, you only get one shot at attacking a particular enemy base.

There's some tiny chance that you could meet them again in matchmaking, but in practice it's probably unlikely to happen.